# Extracting hashtags from tweets texts

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7, tweets

Have read the csv file in pandas. Trying to extract the hashtags in another column using the entities column as following. It would be helpful if I can get assist in resolving the error.The dataset link is given below

```
  df = pd.read_csv('tw_climate_.csv'
  df['entities'].map(lambda x:[i['text'] for i in x['hashtags']])
```

But its showing the following error

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-dbbb34b804ce> in <module>
----> 1 df['entities'].map(lambda x:[i['text'] for i in x['hashtags']])

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in map(self, arg, na_action)
   3907         dtype: object
   3908         """
-> 3909         new_values = super()._map_values(arg, na_action=na_action)
   3910         return self._constructor(new_values, index=self.index).__finalize__(
   3911             self, method="map"

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py in _map_values(self, mapper, na_action)
    935 
    936         # mapper is a function
--> 937         new_values = map_f(values, mapper)
    938 
    939         return new_values

pandas\_libs\lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

<ipython-input-4-dbbb34b804ce> in <lambda>(x)
----> 1 df['entities'].map(lambda x:[i['text'] for i in x['hashtags']])

TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Link for the dataset below:

```
 https://ln5.sync.com/dl/73f6cf090/y4harjr9-p8q483tt-gzyi4srg-6rgi8kd7
```

Comment: The `x` (an element of `df['entities']`) is a string. You should use `json.loads` to parse it before processing.

Comment: @DYZ I am new to this. Can you pls guide me in terms of coding, what to do to extract hashtags from entities

Comment: Hi, what is the output of `df.head().to_dict()`?